# Chrome cookies folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, cookies

Where does Google Chrome store its cookies when running on Windows 7?

Answer (score 46):

In Google Chrome go to:

> *Settings > Show Advanced Settings > Privacy and security > Content Settings > Cookies > See all cookies and site data*

Or simply:

```
chrome://settings/siteData
```

In [addition to the location mentioned in another answer](https://superuser.com/questions/292952/chrome-cookies-folder-in-windows-7/292957#292957), Chrome also stores cookies at this location

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\
```

Comment: Does it still store cookies there or only the Cookies file?

Comment: @AlexS Fixed the location in users folder.

Comment: The folder is `User Data` not `UserData`

Answer (score 28):

It's at the following location:

```
C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\
```

You'll need a program like [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) to read it.

Answer (score 13):

Chrome doesn't store cookies in separate text files in a cookies-directory like in IE; It stores all of the cookies together in a single file in the profile folder like Firefox. However, unlike Firefox, it does not use a plain-text file that can easily be edited; rather it stores them in an SQLite3 database in a file called—surprise, surprise—`Cookies` in the [User Data directory](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory) (e.g., `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies`).

You can use an [SQLite editor](https://www.google.com/search?q=sqlite%20edit) to view or modify the cookies, but it is probably easier to just use the built-in editor at `chrome://chrome/settings/cookies`.

Comment: I accidentally uploaded Preferences file `C:\Users\S\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences` am I safe? There seems to be a lot of UIDs in there, are they cookies? @Synetech

Comment: @Shayan, For the most part, it's probably just your name in your Windows user-directory (`C:\Users\S`), possibly a local directory where you set Chrome to save downloads, the URLs of sites you changed the zoom on, and maybe the last site you were on. Open the file in a text-editor (Notepad would work fine) and do a search for anything you don't want people to see such as your name and email address, as well as `://` and `:\`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look up the cookies from one particular website, I think that the best way is to go on given website and use the developer tools from chrome or firefox (F12 / Ctrl+Maj+i). You can browse the cookies in the ressources tab.