# Where does Chrome store its cookie file?

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, cookies, delphi

AFAIK Google Chrome uses an SQLite file to save cookies. I've tried to locate this file under my Windows 7 but couldn't locate it.

I've found one file only, under `C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`, but it didn't have SQLite extension, and even when I even tried to open it using an SQLite browser, it didn't recognize the file.

I know I can see those cookies from Chrome settings section, but I am trying to read the cookies file content through my Delphi project, so I will appreciate it so much if anyone can please help me by telling me where I can find Google Chrome cookies SQLite file or how I can read Google Chrome cookies file.

Comment: Try the `c:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies` file.

Comment: This is not a programming question; I've voted to move it to Super User.

Comment: @TLama Please check my question, I've noted there that I've already tried the cookies file under this path and it is of no use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find a solution on SuperUser :

[Chrome cookies folder in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/292952/chrome-cookies-folder-in-windows-7)

```
C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\
```

You'll need a program like SQLite Database Browser to read it.

Comment: I've noted in my question that I've already tried this path before and there is no SQLite DB under it

Comment: Apologies, it seems that my confusion was due to using FireFox SQLite extension which didn't open files unless they have SQLite...

I've tried use http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/ and it opened the file :) 

Thanks for your help

Comment: Note: If you have multiple Chrome profiles, that last folder ("Default") is your profile name, which can be found by typing "chrome://version" in browser and looking at last part of Profile Path.

Answer (score 8):

We already have Mac OS X and Windows here, so I'll just add Linux for the benefit of web searchers.

You can find the cookies database at

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/
```

If you can find it there, I'll have you know that the `~/.config/` part comes from where you or your distribution have set the variable `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` to point at.

*Freedesktop.org*, the standards body for this specification, recommends `~/.config/` to be the default and that's what distros follow.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who needs this on Mac OS X, the file is located at `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Cookies`

Answer (score 3):

To access Google Chrome cookies, in order to remove a specific one:

- Click the button (3 horizontal bars, upper right of browser) to customize and control Google Chrome.
- Select 'Settings'
- scroll to bottom and select 'Show Advanced Settings...'
- Under Privacy' click the 'Content Settings' button
- Under 'Cookies' click the 'All cookies and site data...' button

This shows you a list of all site cookies, by site name.