# Google Chrome SQLite cookies contains keywords : drugs, illegal and pornography?

Tags: google-chrome, security, cookies

I was just testing some things with cookies in Chrome.

I opened Local Storage and its content with SQLite browser.

Then I found something weird...

```
{"http://***.***.***.***:8080/jforum/forums/list.do;jsessionid=220352517DF78EEB22901545244A2C59":{"rating":-1,"weight":-1,"flagmask":null,
"flags":{
"shopping":null,
"social":null,
"news":null,
"it":null,
"corporate":null,
"pornography":null,
"violence":null,
"gambling":null,
"drugs":null,
"illegal":null},
```

Pornography ? drugs ? illegal ?? 
What are these for ?

I used Chrome in incognito mode.

Here is the full content. 
This comes from

```
C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\chrome-extension_gomekmidlodglbbmalcneegieacbdmki_0.localstorage

{"http://***.***.***.***:8080/jforum/forums/list.do;jsessionid=220352517DF78EEB22901545244A2C59":{"rating":-1,"weight":-1,"flagmask":null,"flags":{"shopping":null,"social":null,"news":null,"it":null,"corporate":null,"pornography":null,"violence":null,"gambling":null,"drugs":null,"illegal":null},"phishing":1,"phishingDomain":1,"is_typo":false,"block":0,"ttl":3600,"ttl_multi":3600,"ttl_phishing":0,"expireTime":"20140919092944","expireTimeMulti":"20140919102944"},"http://172.16.0.27:8080/jforum/forums/list.do":{"rating":-1,"weight":-1,"flagmask":null,"flags":{"shopping":null,"social":null,"news":null,"it":null,"corporate":null,"pornography":null,"violence":null,"gambling":null,"drugs":null,"illegal":null},"phishing":1,"phishingDomain":1,"is_typo":false,"block":0,"ttl":3600,"ttl_multi":3600,"ttl_phishing":0,"expireTime":"20140919093249","expireTimeMulti":"20140919103249"}}
```

On the other hand, file `C:\Users\sgis\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies`
shows a different content ** 
I was going to put a photo of the browsed view of the SQLite table but it says I need at least 10 reputation to post images.

**EDIT**

This is the content of the cookie in MS IE. I used MS IE in just 'normal' mode not inPrivate browsing.

```
    jforumUserId
2
172.16.0.27/
1024
2346062080
30470770
320830627
30397345
*
```

To open the cookies set by Chrome I followed these two instructions but which one is the right one ?

[Chrome cookies folder in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/292952/chrome-cookies-folder-in-windows-7/292957#292957)

https://superuser.com/a/496360/369693

Comment: This looks like a function of the site you are on, rather than something being done by Google. This looks like Jforums doing.

Comment: Could be. But this is JForum running on Tomcat on my local machine. If JForum records information on whether a user was visiting porn site or not, it would be very funny.

Comment: I checked MS IE cookies but I didn't see these tags.

Comment: Ok. what version of Jforum are you running?

Comment: JForum Version is 2.1.8. I used Chrome in incognito mode.

Comment: Can't find anything searching the source code. Do you have any sort of plugins running on the site? If you do, please edit your question to add these details.